# PHP inside js ajax function diffuculties

Tags: javascript, php

I have button let's say like this:

```
<button id= $id  onClick="popup($id)">button</button>
```

Now I am trying to use it with ajax function

```
<script>
function popup(id){
alert(" ");
document.write(" ");
}
</script>
```

All I want to do is to make this js function execute the php code.
I think puting it into alert of document.write would be good but this code looks like this below and i have big problems with quotations and everything. I have no idea honestly how to make it all work.
Could someone help me match it up please?

```
echo "<div id='element_to_pop_up'> 
<a class='b-close'>zamknij</a>";
$messages = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM msg WHERE id = "'.$messageid.'" ');
$fetchmessage = mysql_fetch_assoc($messages);
echo $fetchmessage['message'];
 echo "</div>";
```

Comment: alert can have only plain test. Do something like this.
<?php $messages = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM msg WHERE id = "'.$messageid.'" ');
$fetchmessage = mysql_fetch_assoc($messages); ?>
<script> alert('<?php echo $fetchmessage['message']; ?>');</script>

Answer (score 3):

PHP is processed on the server side. So you can not run PHP-code client side.

What I'd do is (here done in jQuery, you could do it with other frameworks as well) to set a data-id="" attribute on your button with the ID echoed from PHP. Then when you click the button, you call a PHP script via AJAX that does something. Like:

**HTML:**

```
<button class="clickme" data-id="<?=$row['id'];?>">button</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.clickme').click(function(){
    $.post( "test.php", { msgId: $(this).data('id') }).done(function( data ) {
        alert("Data loaded: " + data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

**HTML**

```
<button class="clickButton" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>" id=""<?php echo $id; ?>">button</button>
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $('.clickButton').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: {id: id}
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

ajax.php

```
//Set up a mysqli connection here
echo "<div id='element_to_pop_up'><a class='b-close'>zamknij</a>";
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM msg WHERE id = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["id"]) . "'");
$fetchmessage = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $fetchmessage['message'];
echo "</div>";
```

- Avoid to mysql injection
- Use mysqli or PDO instead of mysql function since mysql functions are deprecated.

Answer (score -1):

PHP runs on the server. JS runs in the browser. You will not run one from the other directly.

You can run PHP on the server that echoes a string that will be run as JS in the browser.

You can run JS that uses AJAX to call back to the server to run PHP on the server.

You cannot run PHP in the browser.

You cannot run browser JS on the server (for purposes of this discussion, ignoring all the ways you can).